# Difference between Search REST API and Lists REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, search-api

I'm having difficulty explaining my question, mainly based on the reason for the question itself.  So the whole issue is a circular mess in my head.  I really have a slew of questions.

1. Please confirm that there are in fact two **separate** REST APIs for SharePoint?

First (SEARCH REST API): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

Second (LIST REST API): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

2. If I'm correct, are those the proper names of both APIs?
3. Are they both active, or is one a deprecated API?
4. What is the practical difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me :

**1-** Yes they are two different ways to retrieve data from SharePoint (Technically speaking).

**2-** for the name SharePoint rest api and SharePoint Search rest API (See MSDN)

**3-** Yes both are active and present in SharePoint 2016

**4-** the difference is one is based on search services, so need to take care about indexing and planning your search schema and the second is based on client.svc service with caching so you will get live data (but less performances).

Answer (score 0):

In SEARCH REST API

- There will be no 5000 list item threshold.
- The modifications on data will reflects only after the search crawl in server.

In LIST REST API

- List threshold for 5000 items will be there.
- The modifications on data will be available readily.